# Is talcum powder electrically conductive?

Tags: short-circuit, waterproof

I have a small board that I want to put outside, and for a poor-man's waterproofing I thought of putting the whole thing inside a basic party balloon.  Cheap, convenient, effective, but does the talcum powder inside the balloon cause problems with the circuit?

Comment: why not use a plastic bag?

Comment: a food container may be suitable ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=plastic+food+container&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: I've had an electrical conductivity problem with talcum powder in the past. It seemed to get worse if the applied AC frequency was above 40 kHz and if the talcum powder was warmed. This was in a metal detector application where th talc appeared to produce a false signal.

Comment: plastic bags generate static electricity and also tend to develop small holes.  A small balloon wraps nicely around a board due to its elasticity.

Answer (score 1):

Talc like most other minerals is non conductive

Comment: A really good insulator provided it’s dry.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to this? It might depend on the OP’s usage.

Comment: @BlairFonville you need a reference that water conducts electricity?

Comment: The dryness is the main issue; if there is some humidity in the air, does it become conductive?

Comment: it has to be actually damp

Comment: @SolarMike No. What? I need a reference that talc doesn't.

Comment: @BlairFonville Captain Codeman might - you don't.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know if you have a point there or not, but I was maintaining your first person usage in "you need a reference that water conducts electricity?"

Comment: @BlairFonville but water is not talc - are you getting them muddled?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, that's it. I was getting talc and water confused. Thanks for the clarification.